# Android game rpg inventory system

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am using an ArrayList as my "inventory".
I am having trouble figuring out a way to add multiples of the same item without taking up a spot in the "inventory". For example: I add a potion to my inventory. Now I add ANOTHER potion but this time instead of adding ANOTHER potion to the inventory, it should instead show that I have: Potions x 2, while only taking up one spot in the ArrayList. I have come up with a few solutions but I feel as if they are bad practices. One solution I tried was to add an AMOUNT variable to the item itself and increment that. Help me find a much better solution?

EDIT: Ok please ignore the above. I have gotten pretty good answers for that but what surprised me was that there were almost no tutorials on role playing game inventory systems. I've done a lot of google searching and cannot find any good examples/tutorials/source code. If anyone could point me to some good examples/tutorials/source code (does not matter what language, but preferable java, or even c/c++) I would appreciate it, thanks. Oh, and any books on the subject matter.

Comment: Check out this nice open-source game http://www.epiar.net/

Comment: It's an interesting question.  The best data structure to use is going to depend on a lot of design questions though: like is the number of possible items small and finite or very large, is there a slot capacity or item or weight capacity, is it sorted automatically or by the player, what type of queries will the rest of the game code need to be doing, etc...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The usual way to solve this (using the standard API) is to use a `Map<Item, Integer>` that maps an item to the number of of such items in the inventory.

To **get the "amount"** for a certain item, you then just call `get`:

```
inventory.get(item)
```

To **add something** to the inventory you do

```
if (!inventory.containsKey(item))
    inventory.put(item, 0);

inventory.put(item, inventory.get(item) + 1);
```

To **remove something** from the inventory you could for instance do

```
if (!inventory.containsKey(item))
    throw new InventoryException("Can't remove something you don't have");

inventory.put(item, inventory.get(item) - 1);

if (inventory.get(item) == 0)
    inventory.remove(item);
```

This can get messy if you do it in many places, so I would recommend you to encapsulate these methods in an `Inventory` class.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure about this idea; depends how the inventory's represented of course, but this means you can only have one stack of each item type. If there's any notion of inventory 'slots', this won't work.

Comment: Aha, true. Then one would probably add an intermediate `List` for the stacks. But the data structure starts to be complicated, so I'd probably factor out a class somewhere here.

Comment: +1: I would write the add count as `int add = ... ; Integer count = inventory.get(item); if (count == null) inventory.put(item, add); else inventory.put(item, count + add);`

Answer (score 6):

Similar to aioobe's solution, you can use [TObjectIntHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/TObjectIntHashMap.html).

```
TObjectIntHashMap<Item> bag = new TObjectIntHashMap<Item>();

// to add `toAdd`
bag.adjustOrPutValue(item, toAdd, toAdd);

// to get the count.
int count = bag.get(item);

// to remove some
int count = bag.get(item);
if (count < toRemove) throw new IllegalStateException();
bag.adjustValue(item, -toRemove);

// to removeAll
int count = bag.remove(item);
```

---

You can create a multiples class.

```
class MultipleOf<T> {
    int count;
    final T t;
}

List bag = new ArrayList();
bag.add(new Sword());
bag.add(new MultipleOf(5, new Potion());
```

Or you can use a collection which records multiples by count.

e.g. a [Bag](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/Bag.html)

```
Bag bag = new HashBag() or TreeBag();
bag.add(new Sword());
bag.add(new Potion(), 5);
int count = bag.getCount(new Potion());
```

Comment: I am not familiar with a multiples class. What are some uses for these?

Comment: Added an example. You need to wrap the List if you want to update the count or find the quantity easily.

Answer (score 5):

You're probably better off creating a class called `InventorySlot`, with a quantity and contents field. This also give you the flexibility of adding other properties, such as what the inventory slot can contain, should you decide to create a 'potions' only sack or something like that.

Alternatively, a `StackCount` and a boolean `IsStackable`, or perhaps `MaxStack` property is used in quite a few MMO's, it's a perfectly valid technique too.

Answer (score 2):

or an class InventoryField with an item and an integer for the amount.

```
public class InventoryField{
    int count;
    Item item;
}

public class Inventory extends ArrayList<InventoryField>{
       ...
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

How about the following

```
public class Item{
    int count;
    String name;
}
```

Then have a list representing the inventory

```
public class Player {
    List<Item> inventory =  new ArrayLis<Item>();

}
```

Comment: The OP said he already tried having an AMMOUNT variable in the item.