# java inventory checker with contains with method

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android game rpg inventory system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881596/android-game-rpg-inventory-system)

Still stuck on making my rpg in java, there's one method I don't know how to implement. Right now, I want to make an inventory checker for the game, like for example it checks how many herbs are in my pack...how many candies I have in my pack and so on.

How can I implement an inventory for my game and how can I show the players what items are in the inventory present?

Is contains method necessary?

Comment: I have answered just about the same question here before. Here's a link for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881596/android-game-rpg-inventory-system

Comment: @aioobe: great and helpful answer! 1+ and thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented an inventory in my Java game Tyrant many years ago which you might find useful.

Most of the code is in the "Thing" class, which implement an inventory:

https://github.com/mikera/tyrant/blob/master/src/main/java/mikera/engine/Thing.java

Key things to consider:

- An ArrayList or a single is pretty much all you need in terms of data structure to represent an inventory.
- You may want to "stack" multiples of the same item into a single item with a count. If you do this then you need to search the inventory for similar items when you add a new Thing, and increment the count if found. You also need all possible inventory objects to implement a "count" property or similar (which is just 1 for single items)

Comment: thank you i will try to see and study this :)

Comment: @JanraeMendoza: you'll be doing a lot of reading -- that's a huge code base! Thanks for posting the link mikera, 1+

Comment: Yeah, the Tyrant engine at the time was pretty much state-of-the-art: full prototype-based object model, scriptable properties, arbitrary object modifiers, world generation etc. Often wish I'd had the time to finish it properly!

Comment: It's definitely something that I will try to study as well. Again, thanks for the link!