# Java: How to Display My HashTable Inventory?

Tags: java, hashtable, lwjgl, slick2d, inventory

So i made an inventory like in this answer:
[Android game rpg inventory system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881596/android-game-rpg-inventory-system)

My question is whats the best way to display a gui of it on the screen. If it helps ill add im using Slick2D.

Comment: There isn't actually any "best" way at all. Displaying and creating GUI depends on various things. Like is it a game or? which kind of game, the amount of UI elements, etc.

Comment: @Vallentin Im doing a sandbox/rpg game what kind of inventory you suggest? Or whats the best way to do 1? Also I want it to have 50 Slots

Comment: Like I said, there aren't any "best" way. It's a matter of taste. Create the GUI how you want it to look, if you make a UI and you don't like it, change it. Then when you like it, keep it.

Comment: @Vallentin Ok, I understand but how can i create an inventory making it fully functional and also be able to display it. Like in the hashtable im able to put Items ID and Amount but im no able to assign them a slot. its anyway i can do a hashtable or map or something, defining 3 objects so i can get slot id also?

Comment: If you want to "put" multiple values to one key, make a `class Item` and within the `class Item` you can have all the variables you want.

Comment: @Vallentin That Sounds Good, Can you link me an Example or Tutorial?

Comment: A tutorial for how to create a class? If you don't know that then, I would advice you to learn that before you start to play with something like LWJGL and Slick2D.

Comment: @Vallentin Lol I mean how to do it in this case in particular, I dont have idea how the constructor works. And never had to use it before.

Comment: I've made an answer, I'm not 100% sure that is what you mean, but I gave it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you mean, in the comment.

To add "multiple" values to one key in a `Map`, then basically just create your own `class Something` to store all the values, objects, etc. you want it to.

This is pretty sketchy. Though first you would create the `class Something` in our case `class Item` like I said in the comments.

```
public class Item
{
    public static enum ItemType { FOOD, WEAPON, TOOL, ARMOR; }

    public ItemType type;
    public int weight;

    public Item() {

    }

    public Item(ItemType type, int weight) {
        this.type = type;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

Then after when you want to create and add items to your `Map` you would do the following. Where of course the `Map` key is a `Integer` because it would be the inventory index, which is what I get the feeling you're using.

```
HashMap<Integer, Item> inventory = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();

Item i1 = new Item(ItemType.FOOD, 10);
Item i2 = new Item(ItemType.WEAPON, 20);

inventory.put(0, i1);
inventory.put(1, i2);
```

If you don't want/need a dynamic inventory, then instead of using a `Map` you could just use an array of the `class Item`.

```
Item[] inventory = new Item[10];
```

Where 10 is the maximum amount of Items in the Inventory.

Comment: This should work thank you so much. And sorry for taking your time.

Comment: You're welcome, and the amount of time it took doesn't matter!